# uncompyle6 gives success message but output is not readable

Tags: python, decompile

I am trying to use uncompyle6 to decompile a `.pyc` code. I even tried `--verify` option. It says

> Successfully decompiled file

but the output only contains strings like `\xe0\xb3\x0bh\x90`.

What should I do?

Comment: Try it with your own `.pyc` file (obtained from your own valid `.py` file) to be sure that the output in your question is not a consequence of the *invalid `.pyc` file.*

Answer (score 2):

Something is wrong with your input `.pyc` file — probably *it isn't a valid Python bytecode file* (obtained from a valid `.py` source file).

`\xe0`,  `\xb3`, `\x0b`, `\x90` are hexadecimal codes for bytes which have *no printable ASCII representation* — mainly above `0x7F` (127 decimal), but also the control character \x0b (VT - Vertical Tabulation).
(The letter `h` after `\xb3` **is** an ASCII character.)

It's standard Python output for non-ASCII characters in *binary sequence types (bytes / bytearrays / memoryview):*

```
>>> bytes((33, 50, 65, 97))                  # ASCII chars
b'!2Aa'
```

```
>>> bytes((224, 179, 11, 144))               # non-ASCII (4 of "your" 5 bytes)
b'\xe0\xb3\x0b\x90'
```

The same for your byte sequence with non-ASCII and ASCII codes
(now for a change in hexadecimal):

```
>>> bytes((0xe0, 0xb3, 0x0b, 0x68, 0x90))    # "your" byte sequence
b'\xe0\xb3\x0bh\x90'
```